# Sorting and arranging data Excel

Tags: excel

Alright I have searched and google'd.. I have an excel spreadsheet for each day of the week. In this spreadsheet the information that is logged is as follows:
1. Did the ambulance come available on time? If not, how many minutes early or late?
2. Who was the crew, and what was the reason for being late.

What I'd like to do in a separate sheet is search the data and print anyone that has been late more than one time. I'd also like to add the amount of time they've been late accumulatively for that week.

I'd also like to do the same thing for the people that are coming available early and add the amount of time they've added by doing so.

What I've done so far is add a few IF statements in a separate row. IF(J17 = "Late Sign-On", "Check", ""). This has helped me know who is late but it's kind of adding more work since it is already recording who is late etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try sumifs() ie sum the time for each name

Comment: I'll start googling that now. How would I plug a name into the sumif? That's where I'm getting hung up.. Sorting the names and printing out the names that appear more than once..

Comment: Perhaps on a separate sheet have a full list of names and test for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any idea of your data and how it is laid out I have built an example of the use of SUMIFS() below.

The Names is the list of all the names you have and this and the calculation can be on a separate sheet.

[image: Sumifs() example]